# What is the correct BigQuery syntax for SHA256 cryptographic hashing?

Tags: encryption, hash, google-bigquery, sha256

According to [this announcement](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=826), Google BigQuery now supports SHA256 encryption calls in SQL (bypassing the previous need to use embedded JavaScript.) However, the documentation for the function isn't yet live according to the post.

We tried "SELECT SHA256('string_value')..." but the function is not recognized.

Anyone have early knowledge on what is the correct syntax for SHA256 encryption on BigQuery?

Comment: (SHA256 is hashing not encryption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new function is supported in Standard SQL mode only!

Comment: Great - yes - we were able to get the syntax above to work by unchecking the defaulted option for us in BigQuery: "Use legacy SQL" under the Show Options menu.

Comment: [Documentation for the hash functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#hash-functions).